# Using adolc for the sign function in c++

Tags: c++, automatic-differentiation

Here is an implementation of the sign function in C++ using Adolc librairy for automatic differentiation.

```
template<class Tdouble> Tdouble sgn(const Tdouble  &x) 
{ 
  Tdouble s_plus, s_minus, half(.5);
  // set s_plus to sign(x)/2,  except for case x == 0, s_plus = -.5 
  condassign(s_plus,  +x, -half, +half);
  // set s_minus to -sign(x)/2, except for case x == 0,s_minus = -.5 
  condassign(s_minus, -x, -half, +half);
  // set s to sign(x)
  return 0.5*(1-(s_plus - s_minus));
}
```

My question is:
why do we need to compute s_minus and s_plus ? what are the advantages ?

What if I use simply :

```
template<class Tdouble> Tdouble sgn(const Tdouble  &x) 
{ 
  Tdouble res;
  condassign(res,x,1,-1);
  return res;
}
```

Comment: This is not the code for the heaviside but the sign function

Comment: Furthermore, the sign function has three return values: -1 for x < 0, 0 for x = 0 and 1 for x > 0, so your version doesn't consider the middle case.

Comment: true. So it's only to consider the case where $x=0$ ? However for numerical computations, we cannot handle such case ?

Comment: Why can't we? Multiplication by 0 for example yields an exact 0 result.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it is supposed to be sign function ?

According to this https://projects.coin-or.org/ADOL-C/browser/stable/2.1/ADOL-C/doc/adolc-manual.pdf?format=raw in section 1.8, `condassign(a,b,c,d)` is equal to

```
a = (b > 0) ? c : d
```

So the function posted is actually giving Heaviside function and not the sign function. It implements this function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x < 0 \\
1/2 & x = 0 \\
1 & x > 0
\end{cases}
$$
If $x > 0$

```
s_plus = -1/2, s_minus = 1/2, result = 1
```

If $x=0$

```
s_plus = s_minus = 1/2, result = 1/2
```

If $x < 0$

```
s_plus = 1/2, s_minus = -1/2, result = 0
```